# Can't display a simple CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just trying to display a simple gradient into my view controller.
This code doesn't work (view stays white).

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ly = CAGradientLayer()
        ly.frame = view.bounds
        ly.colors = [UIColor.orangeColor(), UIColor.blackColor()]
        ly.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        println(view.bounds) // (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)

        view.layer.addSublayer(ly)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Interestingly, if I set `ly.backgroundColor` to orange, the view becomes orange.
We can conclude the layer is effectively on top of the view but the gradient isn't effective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ly.colors = [UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor]
```

`ly.colors` is of type [AnyObject] but expects CGColor objects. Swift wasn't giving any errors about this because of the [AnyObject], but wasn't working because it needed [CGColor].

Comment: While this line of code may solve the problem, it would be better for the quality of this site and for future users with the same issue to add a brief explanation of how this answers the OP question. Please review [answer] and welcome to Stack Overflow.